# How does SQL Server deal with a missing tempDB?

Tags: ssd, sql-server, azure

Azure has announced the new "D" series of VM's where the temporary drive resides on a SSD

I was planning to use this as the tempDB, it should speed up SQL somewhat with faster temoDB access. However,data on this drive may be lost at any reboot.

In such a situation, how does SQL deal with the loss? Is this supported behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing TempDB and also Buffer Pool Extensions on SSDs is supported in Azure VMs.

Look at http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2014/09/25/using-ssds-in-azure-vms-to-store-sql-server-tempdb-and-buffer-pool-extensions.aspx